# How do I record traffic for an iOS/Android App developed with Firebase SDK?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, jmeter, load-testing

I tried recording traffic for an iOS APP built with Firebase SDK using JMeter. I had configured JMeter and the mobile device properly following all steps in their documentation. I have also installed the Jmeter certificates on the mobile.

Jmeter was able to record HTTP/HTTPS traffic for non-Firebase API calls but was unable to do so wherever the app used the Firebase SDK.

Is there an alternative or a way to record traffic wherever the app used the Firebase SDK?

Goal - After capturing the traffic my intention is to run a load test on the app.

Thanks.

---Edits

I have tried capturing requests the app makes through Firebase using Fiddler and JMeter without any success.

Comment: you can add google analytic into your application to monitor screen , button clicks and all...

Comment: The Firebase platform consists of many products, and the wire protocols vary between these products. What specific part are you using/trying to record?

Comment: I have tried capturing requests the app makes through Firebase using Fiddler and JMeter without any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot record your Firebase traffic using JMeter most probably it means that your application relies on [Firebase Cloud Messaging XMPP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref). It means that JMeter cannot record and replay this type of traffic but in theory you should be able to use [XMPP Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPSampler/) in order to load test Firebase API calls.

Check out [XMPP Load Testing - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide) article to get started.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, For this I will be needing the IP address or the name of the XMPP server. I cannot get these details if I am unable to record the traffic.